Open new browser tab from visual studio code extension running in code-server
From a visual studio code extension running within visual studio code server and rendering within an ordinary web browser, how can I programmatically open a new browser tab? If this is not possible, how might I render a link to the user with target set to _blank, as in <a href="..." target="_blank">?
